# how to place two divs in blocks next to each other

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to place two separate `div` in blocks, one is the name and the names.

This is the [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oem6r3eL/5/)

now the names block must appear as a separate block next to the name `div` regardless of responsiveness. how to achieve that.

the `div` should not wrap around one another

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/oem6r3eL/6/) what you want ?

Comment: yes but without bootstrap class, only the divs

Comment: then why did you posted with bootstrap-tag ?

Comment: the main div is within a bootstrap class, the rest has to be only the divs..can it be done?

Comment: your question is very unclear.

Comment: ok, this bootstrap class is part of two other bootstrap columns, now the divs within that column has to be placed next to each other in blocks similarly in the fiddle you posted, but as divs instead of giving them a bootstrap class..

Comment: Then why to use bootstrap ?

Comment: ok forget there is a bootstrap, now only with the divs will it be possible to place them next to each other

Comment: yes,It is possible.Bootstrap is far better to use.

Comment: yes i know that is what i did, but my boss says to put it in a div since the arrows and name block are not in series i.e., the name goes below the arrow

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.left{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display:block;
  float: left;
  width:50%
}

.right{
   margin: 0px;
   padding:0px;
   display:  block;
   width:50%;
   float:right;
}
 
 .arrow{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.arrow li:before{
  content: '\f0da';
  font-family:'FontAwesome','sans-serif';
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: #922B38;
}
```

```html
  <div class="left">
    <ul class="arrow">
      Name block
      <li>Name</li>
      <li>Name</li>
      <li>Name</li>
      <li>Name</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <ul class="arrow">
    Names block
    <li>Names</li>
    <li>Names</li>
    <li>Names</li>
    <li>Names</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` with `width` to achieve the effect:

```
.left{
  float: left;
  width:50%;
}

.right{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oem6r3eL/7/